# Change contents of SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to remove items from a SelectList?

Comment: Please be more specific, post code, etc

Comment: @Francisco Please see my comments to SLaks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No; it's immutable.

Instead, you can build a copy with a `Where` call:

```
var copy = new SelectList(original.Items.Cast<...>().Where(...));
```

Comment: I'm binding an enum to my SelectList. Could you illustrate your solution a little more I'm not familiar with the Cast part or how I can use the solution.

Comment: @rod: `Items` is an untyped `IEnumerable`.  You need to call `Cast` to convert it to an `IEnumerable<T>` that can be used with LINQ.

Comment: For example: `original.Items.Cast<SomeEnum>().Where(e => e != something)`

Comment: @rod: How are you assigning the enum values to the SelectList? I was under the impression that SelectList needs an IEnumerable and Enum doesn't implement that interface. Please post the code you are using to populate the SelectList in the first instance.